# Click a button on a webpage without opening browser (Android)

Tags: android, html, http, button

I have a website with a button that when clicked displays a message.
My site example: http://catcheat.net/Test/test.html
I am creating an application which should show the message that the button of my site has generated.
I wanted to know if there is some way that allows me to press that button (and then generate the text) without having to open the browser??
And most of all I wanted to know if you can take the text that was generated from the button and show it in my app (without opening the browser of course)??

Comment: You should get a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: @SameerShaikh I don't have any code.. I was asking if there is a way to do what I asked. I don't need any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I quite understand your question, but here I will try
As said JSoup is a Java library providing a set of API to extract and manipulate HTML files. There are several methods to read and parse an HTML page; in our case we want to retrieve it from a remote server and then we have to provide an URL.
[For more information visit link](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/parsing-html-in-android-with-jsoup.html)